# concating char* in c fails do to segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Im trying to create two paths in order to copy file from one folder to another.
I get Segmentation fault on the second time Im trying to concat args[1].
Tried copy the cell to another char with strcpy but it wouldnt help. and a lot more stuff I didnt succeed with.
I guess something with those string commands is messing with my char array and doesnt let me do the concat twise.
the path should be of the form 
"Server/File#" 
or "Client#/File#"
the # is the argument from args.
I looked all over and saw some similar things but not exactly that.
please help.

all the needed "include" are in there.

```
void copy_file(char *args[]){
char dst_path[100],src_path[100];

memset(dst_path,0,100);
memset(src_path,0,100);

strcpy(dst_path,"Client");
strcat(dst_path,args[0]);
strcat(dst_path,"/File");
strcat(dst_path,args[1]);

strcpy(src_path,"Server/File");
strcat(src_path,args[1]);
}
```

Comment: Also `i` is never declared and you should really use memset.

Comment: did both... still no solution..

Comment: Side note: The fact that you're starting with `strcpy` makes the call to `memset` redundant. And by the way, you may as well set them upon declaration (performance-wise it would be more or less the same as calling `strcpy`, but code-wise it would be cleaner).

Comment: just printed them like this- printf("%s , %s",args[0],args[1]);
worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is supposed to segfault because there is no bounds checking and you can easily overflow the destination buffers.

Also, you do not check the number of elements in `args[]` array. There may be fewer arguments than you expect, probably `args[1]` is `NULL`.

---

To fix:

1. Check the number of elements in `args[]` array.
2. Calculate the required buffer size for your final string, allocate a buffer of that size and then format the string. Alternatively, use `snprintf` to format the string in one call. `snprintf` does bound checks for you, so that you do not overflow your destination buffer, e.g:

   ```
   char dst_path[16384];
   int n = snprintf(dst_path, sizeof dst_path, "Client %s /File %s", args[0], args[1]);
   if(n >= sizeof dst_path)
       // dst_path is not large enough
   ```

Comment: hey, in the previews edition of the qeustion, the buffer was at the size it should be but people here told me it wold flow out. so I enlarged it. Im checking the snprintf right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can gather from this where you have mis-stepped. Tested with GCC 4.8.3. The long and short of it is that you are overflowing your buffer.

```
/* gcc -g -Wall -Wextra main.c */
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 30

void copy_file(char* args[]) {
  char dst_path[BUFSIZE];
  char src_path[BUFSIZE];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) { //initializing - tried without it too.
    dst_path[i] = 0;
    src_path[i] = 0; }

  assert(strlen(dst_path) + strlen("Client") < BUFSIZE);
  strcpy(dst_path, "Client");
  assert(strlen(dst_path) + strlen(args[0]) < BUFSIZE);
  strcat(dst_path, args[0]);
  assert(strlen(dst_path) + strlen("/File") < BUFSIZE);
  strcat(dst_path, "/File");
  assert(strlen(dst_path) + strlen(args[1]) < BUFSIZE);
  strcat(dst_path, args[1]);

  assert(strlen(src_path) + strlen("Server/File") < BUFSIZE);
  strcpy(src_path, "Server/File");
  assert(strlen(src_path) + strlen(args[1]) < BUFSIZE);
  strcat(src_path, args[1]); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  copy_file(&argv[1]);
  return 0; }
```

Comment: You do not need to initialize entire buffers with zeros. Only the first element.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, true. I was minimizing the changes to the code in question.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, fair enough. If I were truly minimizing code changes I should have left the dead variables there too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons you are having buffer overflows most likely is your use of `strcpy`.  This does not have a fixed copy length, and thus if your strings are not terminated by a NULL character `\0` memory that is not part of the string will be copied as well.  What you should use is `strncpy`; then you can use `strlen` to get the length of the string after adding a terminating NULL character.  It is good practice to always set the last character of your buffer to NULL after writing to it.